# How to override methods in a Scala trait?

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, traits

I have a class that mixes in a number of different traits the encode behavior for matching orders given various available order types. The class definition looks as follows...

```
class DoubleAuctionMarket(val security: Security) extends EventBus {
  this: MatchingEngine =>
```

The relevant parts of the base `MatchingEngine` trait look as follows...

```
trait MatchingEngine {

  /** Implements crossing logic for various types of orders. */
  def crosses(incoming: Order, top: Order): Boolean

  /** Implements price formation rules for various types of orders. */
  def formPrice(incoming: Order, top: Order): Double

}
```

I have another trait called `LimitOrderOnlyMatchingEngine` that extends the base trait as follows...

```
trait LimitOrderOnlyMatchingEngine extends MatchingEngine {

  def crosses(incoming: LimitOrder, top: LimitOrder): Boolean = {

    (incoming, top) match {
      case (incoming: LimitOrderAsk, top: LimitOrderBid) =>
        incoming.limit <= top.limit
      case (incoming: LimitOrderBid, top: LimitOrderAsk) =>
        incoming.limit >= top.limit
    }

  }

  def formPrice(incoming: LimitOrder, top: LimitOrder): Double = top.limit

}
```

Now, when I try to mix in the `LimitOrderOnlyMatchingEngine` using

```
new DoubleAuctionMarket(security) with LimitOrderOnlyMatchingEngine
```

I am told that "object creation is impossible" because neither the `crosses` method nor the `formPrice` method have been implemented as required by the self type annotation I used.

Not sure what is going wrong. I suspect that either:

1. I need to somehow override the relevant methods in the `LimitOrderOnlyMatchingEngine` or
2. I need to define the input types for those methods in the base class differently.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're technically not implementing the two methods in the `MatchingEngine` trait. The trait specifies:

```
def crosses(incoming: Order, top: Order): Boolean
def formPrice(incoming: Order, top: Order): Double
```

But you implemented:

```
def crosses(incoming: LimitOrder, top: LimitOrder): Boolean
def formPrice(incoming: LimitOrder, top: LimitOrder): Double
```

You could solve it with generics (I never remember if it is `+Order` or `-Order` ...) but the other way is that because you're using pattern matching, it will work just by changing the argument types - though you'll probably want to cover the other order types one way or another.

I added stubs for classes like `Order`, `LimitOrder` etc and the following compiles nicely:

```
// NOTE: Order not LimitOrder
def crosses(incoming: Order, top: Order): Boolean = {
  (incoming, top) match {
    case (incoming: LimitOrderAsk, top: LimitOrderBid) =>
      incoming.limit <= top.limit
    case (incoming: LimitOrderBid, top: LimitOrderAsk) =>
      incoming.limit >= top.limit
  }
}

// NOTE: Order not LimitOrder
def formPrice(incoming: Order, top: Order): Double = 0.0 // Note pattern matching needed
```

As a side note, it's great Scala is making headway into the finance world.

Comment: I have a large number of order types and the compiler complains about missed cases when I use `(incoming: Order, top: Order)` signature and then only pattern match for LimitOrder cases. If you add a stub class called `MarketOrder` that extends from `Order` you will see what I mean. How would one solve the problem using generics?

Comment: Hmm, I added ``class MarketOrder(val timeout: Int, override val qty: Int) extends Order(qty)`` and it still runs ok. I'm using Scala 2.10.3.

Comment: A thought that comes to mind though is chaining the pattern match to default handling, like ``def crosses(...): Boolean = {...} orElse defaultCrosses(incoming, top)``.

Comment: I had not thought of chaining the pattern match. That is a good idea.